# Find the first string after character

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, substr

I am trying to find the first character after a special character.
For example:
String: dog/11/99
I want jQuery to find 1(the character after the first /) and then 9(the character after the second /)

```
<table border="1">
   <tr><td class="abc">apple</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="abc">ball</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="abc">cat/55/77</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="abc">dog/11/99</td></tr>
</table>
```

I need to look through the whole table and then give me the character after the special character.

Any idea how I can accomplish that?

Comment: Use a regular expression available in native js.

Comment: `string.split('/').slice(1).map( x => x[0])`

Comment: @adeneo that also returns the very first character

Comment: sorry @adeneo I am a newbie at this... can I get a sample code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/k2fkLg8y/

Comment: Here is a great site to learn about and test regex expressions. http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: [String.prototype.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [string character access](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String#Character_access) offer an alternative approach to regular expression usage.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the Regex:

```
/\/(.)/g
```

That will return the first character after any `/`.
For example:

```
var match, regex = /\/(.)/g;
while (match = regex.exec('dog/11/99')) console.log(match);
// ["/1", "1", index: 3, input: "dog/11/99"]
// ["/9", "9", index: 6, input: "dog/11/99"]
```

with `match[1]` being your desired character.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.match()` with `RegExp` `/\W/` to match character that is not a word character, `.index` of returned array, `String.prototype.slice()`, bracket notation to get selected character at index of string.

```js
var str = document.querySelector("table tr:last-child td").textContent;
var index = str.match(/\W/).index;
var res1 = str[index + 1];
var res2 = str.slice(index, str.length).match(/\W/).index;
var res2 = str[
             str.slice(index + 1, str.length).match(/\W/).index + 1 
             + index + 1
           ];

console.log(res1, res2);
```

```html
<table border="1">
   <tr><td class="abc">apple</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="abc">ball</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="abc">cat/55/77</td></tr>
   <tr><td class="abc">dog/11/99</td></tr>
</table>
```